# cannot add the following dependency in pom.xml file

Tags: java, reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot, maven

I am building a project using `React`, `Springboot` and `MongoDB`

I wanted to add dependency with group `id:me.paulschwarz` and `artifact id`: spring-dotenv and version `2.5.4`, but my ide(`Intellij`) gives me the following problems:

```
 Dependency 'me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:2.5.4' not found
 Dependency 'me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:2.5.4' not found
 Dependency 'me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:2.5.4' not found
 Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
 Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
```

moreover when I try to run my spring-boot application I get the following errors:

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2023-06-19T17:04:01.904+05:30 ERROR 20836 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: An SRV host name '${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at dev.ayushKasara.movies.MoviesApplication.main(MoviesApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: An SRV host name '${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SRV host name '${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
        at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.<init>(ClusterSettings.java:594) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.<init>(ClusterSettings.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings$Builder.build(ClusterSettings.java:370) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.<init>(MongoClientSettings.java:957) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.<init>(MongoClientSettings.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.build(MongoClientSettings.java:600) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:50) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
         23 common frames omitted
```

all I did was create a `.env` file in resources, these are its content of `.env` file:

```
MONGO_DATABASE = "movies-api-db"
MONGO_USERNAME = "f20191081"
MONGO_PASSWORD = "AshuGunna98"
MONGO_CLUSTER = "cluster0.oobowit.mongodb.net"
```

and added a new line in my `.gitignore` file: `.env`

my `application.properties` file contains this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database = ${env.MONGO_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://${env.MONGO_USER}:${env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}
```

these above 2-3 lines will help to connect with my MongoDB database (as I understood it)

Can anyone suggest changes to my `pom.xml` file since I think that is the source of my errors or just help me with a solution for this problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.ayushKasara</groupId>
    <artifactId>movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movies</name>
    <description>A simple API related movies</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Remove the space around `=` in your `.env` and in your `properties`. The spaces are causing your issue (at least one of them).

Comment: hey, the error still persists something i missed out in the question was that intellij was highlighting me.paulschwarz  and spring-dotenv as red meaning they are giving some problem ?

Comment: Investigate what IntelliJ is trying to tell you. Alternatively pay close attention what Maven might print on the console. You dependency exists on maven central: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.paulschwarz/spring-dotenv

Answer (score 1):

Since it was updated try to use new version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also don't forget that from version 3 there is no need to use **env** in places where you put variables. In your case it will look like:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database = ${MONGO_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://${MONGO_USER}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_CLUSTER}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you declared `MONGO_USERNAME` in `.env` file and my `.application.properties` as `env.MONGO_USER`. That's the issue.